# How can you have a hotel to have a Schema.org rating based on the hotel star rating system?

Tags: seo, html, microdata, rich-snippets, schema.org

How would you write microdata for hotels with ratings classified as "1-star" to "5-star" hotels? Looking at http://schema.org/Hotel, I see no "Rating" property but only an "aggregateRating" one which is for multiple ratings from reviews. For reference, here's an explanation of the Star Rating system http://www.hotels.com/customer_care/star_rating.html

Here' s an example of my markup code:

```
<div class="container mt30" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7" itemprop="brand" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Hotel">
            <span style="font-size:24px" itemprop="name">Hotel Name</span>

            <span class="hidden" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
                <span itemprop="ratingValue">3.5</span>
                <span itemprop="worstRating">1</span>
                <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span>
                <span itemprop="ratingCount">1</span>
            </span>
...
```

I'm guessing I would need something like this:

```
<span class="hidden" itemprop="rating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
    <span itemprop="ratingValue">3.5</span>
    <span itemprop="worstRating">1</span>
    <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span>
</span>
```

However, it seems that code would be invalid microdata. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting thought!! That is not the intent of the schema.org mark-up which can be quite limited. I wonder why on-one has ever thought of using that way before?? It is the first time it has been suggested that I have seen. I am not sure if it would not be misleading though. Not meaning that is your intent of course, but a by product.

Answer (score 2):

Types and properties for hotels [are proposed](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/pull/916) and will likely be part of the next Schema.org release (2.3).

In this proposal, [`Hotel`](http://sdo-hotels.appspot.com/Hotel)¹ can have the property [`starRating`](http://sdo-hotels.appspot.com/starRating)¹:

> An official rating for the lodging business, e.g. from national associations or standards bodies. Use the name property of a PropertyValue for indicating the type of the rating (e.g. HOTREC, DEHOGA, WHR, or Hotelstars).

You can see some [more documentation](http://sdo-hotels.appspot.com/docs/hotels.html) about it under the "Star Rating" section.

---

¹ **Don’t** use this URI for your data, it’s just a snapshot of the current proposal, used for review, discussion etc. Related issue: [Stars for Hotel/LodgingBusiness](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/780)

Answer (score 1):

Traditional hotel star ratings are not based on reviews and would not be appropriate to use the `aggregateRating`.   Instead the stars are an [award](https://schema.org/award) and if you wish to represent them in schema.org you should do it like this:

```
Rated <span itemprop="award">★★★★☆</span> by the Hotelstars Union.
```